# How can I get a road network to run a simulation on?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, data, routing

I'm new to GIS and I'm asking this a bit out of desperation, but I'm trying my best not to get overwhelmed. :)

I want to download a file that contains data of a road network (of what road network is not a concern to me), visualize this road network, but then be able to run a simulation on it (so it can't be an image, i.e. a .jpeg). I'm looking for what resources/software I should use.

(Is there a way I can chat with someone who knows about GIS? I feel that would be better.)

Comment: What sort of simulation do you want to run on the data?

Answer (score 3):

you can get vector data of road network from openstreetmap. They allows you to download osm which can them be converted to PostGIS, shapefile etc. see [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) for conversion details.
try [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) which is a java client for downloading data from openstreetmap. You can find enough tutorials using JOSM [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

you can check out [MATSim](http://www.matsim.org/) - Agent-Based Transport Simulations. it has lots of well-documented tutorials too. there is good video [here](http://vimeo.com/37716331#) on vimeo.

> MATSim provides a framework to implement large-scale agent-based
>   transport simulations. The framework consists of severel modules which
>   can be combined or used stand-alone. Modules can be replaced by own
>   implementations to test single aspects of your own work. Currently,
>   MATSim offers a framework for demand-modeling, agent-based
>   mobility-simulation (traffic flow simulation), re-planning, a
>   controler to iteratively run simulations as well as methods to analyze
>   the output generated by the modules.

[image: matsim]

i hope it helps you..

Comment: I tried out MATSim last week, but in order to visualize the data I had to download their affiliated proprietary software, Via, which is not open-source. Because of this I couldn't do what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about which road network you get, I'd recommend you download some free [TIGER datasets](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2012/layers.cgi).

I would not recommend OSM because it just complicates things unnecessarily. The OSM graph is not routeable by default.

Comment: I found data from where I live (http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/search.do;jsessionid=C86293B5F3A1567FDB0C54D54248B7EA?produit=nrn&language=en) but can you tell me how to open a .sh or .kml file?

Comment: PostGIS comes with a Shapefile Loader. Since you tagged this question PostGIS, I guess that's what you are looking for: shp2pgsql.